# How to add a numerical value into a window frame in SQLite?

Tags: sql, r, sqlite, window-functions

I am having some difficulty in adding a numerical digit into my windows frame specification in SQLite. I am using R in SQLITE. Although if you know how to do this in SQL then that's also helpful.

Here is a link to the sqlite window function documentation - although it's abit hard to understand as to where i should place my numerical value.

https://www.sqlite.org/windowfunctions.html

In particular i am looking at the frame boundary section.

I kepe receiving the error message:

```
Error: unsupported frame specification
```

Any ideas?

My code is the following:

```
"create temp table forward_looking as 
              SELECT *,  
        COUNT( CASE channel WHEN 'called_office'  THEN 1 ELSE null END)
        OVER (PARTITION by special_digs 
        ORDER BY time 
        RANGE FOLLOWING 604800) 
      AS new_count
      from my_data
    ")
```

Basically the code should look at the time column which is in unix epoch time and then find 7 days in advance (which is 604800 in unix time) then add a count to new_count. And do this on a row by row term.

I think I may have the numeric in the `RANGE FOLLOWING` part the wrong way around??

Comment: If you look at the syntax diagram for **frame-spec** in the documentation you linked, is what you're using valid?

Comment: @Shawn so i did have a look at the frame-spec documentation and the syntax diagram was really helpful - it took a while to try and understand it, but i managed to figure it out!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that you want:

```
create temp table forward_looking as 
select 
    d.*,  
    count(*) filter(where channel <> 'called_office') over (
        partition by special_digs 
        order by time 
        range between current row and 604800 following
    ) as new_count
from my_data d
```

That is, the `range` clause requires a starting and ending specification (`between ... and ...`).

Note that I also modified the window function to use the standard `filter` clause, which makes the logic more obvious.

Comment: thanks for the help - i did run this code although i ended up with count values occuring on the channel = 'called office' when I wanted the count values to occur on the other values of the channel column and not on the records with 'called office'

Comment: @BeansOnToast: ok so I think that just need to change the equality to an inequality in the `filter` clause. Query updated.

Comment: yep managed to solve the problem - i did try this whilst using a case when instead of filter clause and it returned the same result so i'm content with the outcome - thanks for your help!